# swift overwrites the text into another varible

Tags: swift

I have an appusermodel where I get it from api and write it into a struct AppUserModel
I have an Utility static class where I store app level variables
I also got some tokens from Api, key_normal, key_token_1, key_token_2

But when I write those variables into Utility variables from model, the last one overwrites the others!!!

here is the code

```
                Utility.CurrentUser = appUserModel;
                
                print(appUserModel.nk000)
                print(appUserModel.tk001)
                print(appUserModel.tk002)
                print("------")
                print("------")
                
                print(appUserModel.nk000)
                Utility.writeString(key: Utility.KEY_NORMAL, value: appUserModel.nk000);
                print(Utility.getStringSafely(strData: Utility.readString(key: Utility.KEY_NORMAL)))
                
                print("-")
                
                print(appUserModel.tk001)
                Utility.writeString(key: Utility.KEY_TOKEN_1, value: appUserModel.tk001);
                print(Utility.getStringSafely(strData: Utility.readString(key: Utility.KEY_NORMAL)))
                
                print("--")
                
                print(appUserModel.tk002)
                Utility.writeString(key: Utility.KEY_TOKEN_2, value: appUserModel.tk002);
                print(Utility.getStringSafely(strData: Utility.readString(key: Utility.KEY_NORMAL)))
                
                print("---")
```

and here is the result

```
2023_ixkA
2023_esdM
2023_yurZ
------
------
2023_ixkA
2023_ixkA
-
2023_esdM
2023_esdM
--
2023_yurZ
2023_yurZ
---
```

the code above should write appUserModel.nk000 to Utility.normalkey but other variables somehow overwrites the Utility.KEY_NORMAL

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the keys in your `write` and `get` calls are correct? Writing to `KEY_TOKEN_1` and then reading `KEY_NORMAL` seems wrong.

Comment: @Gereon thanks for your time, That is my check actually, somehow, when I was writing to KEY_TOKEN_1 , the KEY_NORMAL was changing. but the problem is solved with an answer below

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
In static class, when I define the static variables to the same string text, I guess they share the same pointer so whenever I change one of them they all change.

it used to be like this

```
static var KEY_NORMAL                   =   "";
static var KEY_TOKEN_1                  =   "";
static var KEY_TOKEN_2                  =   "";
```

then when I change the key_token_1 then all 3 changes, when I change key_token_2 then all changes.

now I changed the initial values to something like this

```
static var KEY_NORMAL                   =   "a";
static var KEY_TOKEN_1                  =   "b";
static var KEY_TOKEN_2                  =   "c";
```

now they dont mix with each other when I assign a value to any of them.

now the result is like this

```
2023_ixkA
2023_esdM
2023_yurZ
------
------
2023_ixkA
2023_ixkA
-
2023_esdM
2023_ixkA
--
2023_yurZ
2023_ixkA
```

Comment: `I guess they share the same pointer so whenever I change one of them they all change.` - no, that's not what happens.